# Relay: use constant inside Fragment instead of graphql`...`

Tags: javascript, graphql, relayjs, relay

Relay **createFragmentContainer** is useful feature and it is easy to use:

```
const MyComponent = createFragmentContainer(
    MyFragmentComponent,
    {
        job: graphql`
            fragment MyComponent_job on Job {
                id
            }
        `
    }
);
```

The problem is it really  hard to read code when query is at the end of my file. I prefer to have it at the top right after imports. Like this:

```
const QUERY_FRAGMENT = graphql`
    fragment MyComponent_job on Job {
        id
    }     
`
// Main code here

const MyComponent = createFragmentContainer(
    MyFragmentComponent,
    {
        job: QUERY_FRAGMENT
    }
);
```

But relay compiler throws error in that case: `FindGraphQLTags: 'createFragmentContainer' expects fragment definitions to be 'key: graphql'.`

#### Is there a way to separate `createFragmentContainer` and `graphql`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue with `babel-plugin-relay`. As noted in [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/1698), the workaround is to change your imports:

```
import Relay, { graphql } from 'react-relay'

const fragment = graphql`...`

...

Relay.createFragmentContainer(Component, fragment)
```